# Angular 2 RC 5 Bootstrap custom HTTP class TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

In Angular 2 RC 4 I have a class HttpLoading which extends the original Http service of Angular 2.

With RC 4 I was able to use that in bootstrap without any issue using the below code:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }),
    provide(Http, {
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new HttpLoading(backend, defaultOptions),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    })
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**My DefaultRequest Options class**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    headers: Headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
}
```

**My HttpLoading Class looks like this:**

```
import { Http, RequestOptionsArgs, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {GlobalService} from './globalService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class HttpLoading extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _globalService: GlobalService) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        this._globalService.isLoading = true;
        return super.get(url, options)
            .map(res => {
                this._globalService.isLoading = false;
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

With Angular 2 RC 5 the way bootstrap has been changed and we now need to have NgModule and bootstrap that. I have followed the migration guide and created my below NgModule:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }     from '@angular/http';
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

import { DefaultRequestOptions } from './DefaultRequestOptions';
import { HttpLoading } from './http-loading';

import { routing }        from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions },
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, globalService: GlobalService) => new HttpLoading(backend, defaultOptions, globalService),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, GlobalService]
        },
GlobalService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But now when I use it in my Component, it doesn't sent any request to server and through below error in console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
```

**My component in which I am using http is below:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '../../templates/home/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('/home')
            .subscribe((data) => {

            });
    }
}
```

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much everyone for your help, I was able to resolve the issue by removing

```
{ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions },
```

Which seems to be unnecassary with RC 5.

Comment: Do we need HTTP_PROVIDERS ?

Answer (score 20):

I found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4x0mxt/rc5_error_when_using_http_service/). I had the same problem it worked for me.

Just add a body in in the get options:

```
this.http.get(url, { body: "" });
```

I hope it will work for you too

Comment: For me too. I had the issue on a DELETE request. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, amazingly this worked for me as well. Is this intended behavior? Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Looks like a bug that [will be patched in rc6](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10612)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a typo but I can't see the `GlobalService` class in the provider of your NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        GlobalService, // <----------
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions },
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, globalService: GlobalService) => new HttpLoading(backend, defaultOptions, globalService),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, GlobalService]
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thierry, sorry that was just typo in the question. In my code, I have this in providers list but its still throwing error. "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null"